# Android studio fail to display the layout preview when clicking the design tab in the XML file

Tags: android, xml

When i tried to open the design tab of the XML file in Android Studio. It fail to show it. 
I' ve tried to

1) clean, rebuild the project.

2) Invalidate caches & restart'the project .

Still nothing shows in the Layout preview .Any thoughts. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by clicking on Theme icon and changed the **AppTheme** to another theme.

or change the **API** to another one from the tab above the layout.